# Joining 3 tables with separate where clauses

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

i have 3 tables:

```
USERS(id, username, email, password)

QUESTIONS(id, uid, type, ques, date, time)

ANSWERS(id, a_uid, qid, reply, a_date, a_time)
```

i want to select * from all three tables

```
where $_SESSION[‘id’] = questions.uid

& users.id = questions.uid

& questions.id = answers.qid
```

how can i achieve this?

Comment: please improve this question with an [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select * 
 from USERS
 inner join QUESTIONS  on users.id = questions.userid
 inner join ANSWERS on questions.id = answers.qid
 where  questions.uid = $_SESSION['id'] ;
```

Comment: i get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\trying\notification.php on line 86

Comment: solved! thanku....

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQL joins](http://www.sql-join.com/) for this along with specifying your where clause.

```
 select * 
 from USERS U
 join QUESTIONS Q on U.id = Q.uid
 join ANSWERS A on Q.id = A.qid
 where $_SESSION['id'] = Q.uid ;
```

Comment: i get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\trying\notification.php on line 86

Comment: solved,..... thanxxxxx